# What does the server difficulty property do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While making edits to the `server.properties` file, I noticed there was a difficulty setting, which is currently set to `1`.

I assume this is related to the [client-side setting](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28452/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-difficulty-setting-of-a-saved-minecraft-game/28454#28454) of the same name, but what options are valid in the properties file, and what does each difficulty setting change?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Server Difficulties

The difficulty of a server is configured on the server-side, regardless of what a players client is configured as. The difficulty property is an integer and has 4 potential values. The value defaults to `1`, or easy.

#### Peaceful

Peaceful mode is active when `difficulty=0`. Hunger is disabled, as is eating, and health is regenerated all the time. Hostile mobs spawn if `spawn-monsters` is true, but they are removed immediately. (It is worth, therefore, to also set `spawn-monsters` to false).

#### Easy

Easy is the default difficulty, and is active when `difficulty=1`. Hunger is enabled, but will only cause damage when Steve has more than 5 hearts. Hostile mobs have less health and cause less damage, while creepers have a smaller detection radius.

#### Normal

Normal mode is active when `difficulty=2`. Hunger is enabled, and can cause damage down to 0.5 hearts. Hostile mobs have 'normal' health and cause 'normal' damage (see table).

#### Hard

Hard mode is active when `difficulty=3`. Hunger is enabled, and can kill Steve. Hostile mobs deal greater damage and have a small amount of extra health. Creepers have a larger detection radius for triggering their attacks.

**TL;DR**:

```
| difficulty | id | hunger | zombie/enderman | skeleton | spider | creeper |
+------------+----+--------+-----------------+----------+--------+---------+
| peaceful   | 0  | n/a    | n/a             | n/a      | n/a    | n/a     |
| easy       | 1  | 5      | 1               | 1        | .5     | 5.5     |
| normal     | 2  | 0.5    | 2.5             | 2        | 2.5    | 10      |
| hard       | 3  | 0 (die)| 3.5             | 3        | 3.5    | 10.5    |
```

Comment: +1. It's been a while since I played but is it still the harder the difficulty the less monsters that spawn or has that been changed?

Comment: *Hunger [...] can kill Steve if left unattended*  Not true.  You don't lose health for just standing there.

Comment: Wait, did you mean the hunger can kill Steve if *the hunger* is left unattended?  In that case, you're right.

Comment: @John Yeah, that's what I meant. I was't sure how to phrase it at the time.

Comment: @JohntheGreen I've edited it. It should be clearer now.